# HP Loadrunner - web_reg_save_param_ex freeing memory?

Tags: loadrunner

I am aware that it is required to free the memory after saving using functin like lr_save_string, lr_eval_string_ext, but the documentation didnt mention how web_reg_save_param_ex release memory.

> Does the memory automatically freed at the end of each iteration like lr_eval_string does? if so is there any other similar function that i could manually free the memory?
>   My thought is using lr_free_parameter, but then documentation didnt mention that it would work with web_reg_save_param_ex.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is quote from Function Reference:

The lr_free_parameter function frees the memory allocated at run-time for the specified parameter.
lr_free_parameter frees the memory for parameters created at run-time using functions such as web_reg_save_param or lr_save_string. For other functions that create parameters at run-time, see the String and Parameter Functions and the Web Correlation Functions. For similar functions in other protocols, see the reference for the specific protocol.

IMHO sounds like this function suitable for all kind of run-time parameters created by all existing APIs.

Comment: I second the general use for all parameter types.

Comment: i was so stupid that i can actually check the return value for confirmaton. yes, it is the one. thanks so much!